# Nodejs shared server hosting

Tags: node.js, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to purchase shared hosting with node js support. Can you provide us company name which support nodejs on shared server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had wanted a hosting service with nodejs and decided to go with a Virtual Private Server. You may wish to look into it. They are very reasonable (cheaper than a hosting service) and a fantastic learning experience. I had mine up and running in a couple hours. I love it best thing I ever did. Just search VPScheap

Comment: For starters, I suggest you try out Heroku https://heroku.com, because of their free and easy to use Node.js build pack, but if you want a cheap VPS that runs your production Node.js application, DigitalOcean is a good option, and here I got my DO promote link https://m.do.co/c/8a98631ca2a1, if you designed to use my promote link, in favor, it will give you 10 dollar for free in the startup, and return 25 dollars once you span over 25 dollar

Answer (score 1):

You have many options out there. It depends on what you want to do but I would go for:

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/): It has a free option and it's compatible with integration testing tools like Travis. You can easily configure databases and also create environment variables easily

[Glitch](https://glitch.com/): It's also for free and you can just start programming because the server is already configured. I usually use this service when I want to try some small projects on node.js and I need a server to share what I'm doing.